# return message with parameter in javascript

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net

Can someone help me with the following problem?

```
<asp:LinkButton ID="deleteButton" runat="server" CommandName="Delete" Text="Delete"
    OnClientClick='<%# string.Format("javascript:return confirm({0})",  Eval("Id")   ) %>'   />
```

I have a messagebox with only the 'Id' when i click on delete button. But i want to put some text before the 'Id' like are you sure to delete 'Id'?
Im not so good in javascript so i hope someone can help me
thanks!

Comment: possible duplicate of [confirm message box](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4933969/confirm-message-box)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a JS function that looks like:

```
function confirmDeletion(id) {
  return confirm("Your message here: " + id);
}
```

Then call it from your ASP linkbutton tag onClientClick event handler.

Comment: Try putting The eval tag inside the parentheses.

Comment: OnClientClick='<%# string.Format("javascript:confirmDeletion({0});",  Eval("Id")   ) %>' is the solution. thanks!